# How do I query HTML tag values in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

```
<g class="ABC" transform="translate(786.9,53)" score="1.3">
```

How can I query the score value of this example HTML tag?

I am writing a test to query the score attribute (it is *1.3* in the above example) and compare it with the correct number in my test.

I am not sure how to get the score attributes value. `cy.get()` didn't give me what I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cypress gives you direct access to the DOM. If you want to target a DOM object and operate on it directly, you will want to use the `then()` function.

Here's an example that should work in your case:

```js
cy.get("g.ABC").then(elem => {
    let score = elem.attr("score");
    cy.log(score);
    // etc...
});
```

See [this doc page](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then.html) for more info.

---

If you want to perform a mocha assertion directly on the value, use `should()` to take advantage of automatic retries:

```js
cy.get("g.ABC").should(elem => {
    let score = elem.attr("score");
    // If this assertion fails, the entire block will retry until it doesn't.
    expect(score).to.equal("1.3");
});
```

See [this doc page](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Function) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. It's working for me. Really appreciate it. First day of using Cypress. I thought cypress couldn't query custom attribute. I used to do cy.get().should(have.attr, 'score', ;1.3'). It shows the timeout error.

Comment: getAttribute is not a valid function. Need to use attr instead. So, basically, it should be 'let score = elem.attr("score");'

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @user846316, and sorry for not updating sooner. I'll edit so it's correct.